# Rails nested model form with has_one and has_many inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am using a nested form with has_one and a has_many relation inside it. The problem is that the data in the association is not being saved.

Below are the models, controller and the view I am using

**Sell Order Model**

```
class SellOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_one    :work_order, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_order, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Work Order Model**

```
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sell_order
  has_many   :todos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true  
end
```

**Todo Model**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work_order
end
```

**Sell Order Controller**

```
class SellOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @sell_order = SellOrder.new(user: current_user)
    1.times {
      @work_order = @sell_order.build_work_order
      @work_order.todos.build
    }
  end

  def create
    @sell_order = current_company.sell_orders.new(sell_order_params)
    if @sell_order.save
      redirect_to [:edit, @sell_order]
    else
      1.times {
        @work_order = @sell_order.build_work_order
        @work_order.todos.build
      }
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def sell_order_params
      params.require(:sell_order).permit(:some_other_attributes, work_order_attributes: [todos_attributes: [:comment, :price]])
    end
end
```

**View**

```
= f.fields_for :work_order do |builder_work_order|
  = builder_work_order.fields_for :todos do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control'
    = builder.text_field :price, class: 'form-control'
```

When I submit the form, only the Sell Order is saved. No data goes in work order and todo tables. Does anyone has a solution for this type of situation?

**Rails version: 4.1.1**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do your params look like? (not your seller_order_params)

Comment: Params look like this if I inspect them. **{"work_order_attributes"=>{"todos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"test", "price"=>"123"}}}}**

Comment: does that differ from sell_order_params?

Comment: No. Its the same. I am actually inspecting sell_order_params. We can say that **sell_order_params => {"work_order_attributes"=>{"todos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"test", "price"=>"123"}}}}**

Comment: you are rejecting `work_order_attributes` where content is blank and I see no content in those `params` so it getting rejected and thus nothing below it will be created either. looks like the same would happen to `todos` because again I do not see a content attribute in the `params`.